# How to use os.system() to run `> >(tee -a log)`?

Tags: python, shell, sh, tee

I run the following command in the terminal.

```sh
sh -c "echo out; echo err 2>&1" >>(tee -a stdout.log) 2>>(tee -a stdout.log >&2)
```

output:

```
out  
err
```

Using `os.system` in Python will report an error.

```py
import os
cmd = """
sh -c "echo out; echo err 2>&1" > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stdout.log >&2)
"""
os.system(cmd)
```

```
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
sh: -c: line 1: `sh -c "echo out" > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stdout.log >&2)'
```

Comment: Why did you use a different command string in Python than you used in the terminal?

Comment: It is quite risky (i.e. undefined behaviour) to use the same file, `stdout.log`, for both `tee` statements. It may work sometimes, but it may also break .

Comment: We have two processes appending to the same file simultaneously. Even if `tee` writes to its file unbuffered, there is no guarantee that the two `tee` won't try to write at the same time. The safe way to do it would be IMO to do a `2>&1 | tee -a stdout.log`.

Comment: For other reasons, I don't want stderr> stdout.@user1934428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>(...)` is bash-specific syntax. Make that `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`.

Also you should enclose the entire command in quotes since `-c` expects a single argument.

```
cmd = """
bash -c 'echo out > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stdout.log >&2)'
"""
```

To test writing to both stdout and stderr like your original example, try like this with curly braces:

```
cmd = """
bash -c '{ echo out; echo err 2>&1; } > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stdout.log >&2)'
"""
```